# Adding Newline in string for HTML email body

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm trying to generate an email with some basic formatting based on labels in a FormView. I'm going the route of `Process.Start("mailto:...` instead of System.Net.Mail so the email opens up in the default email client to give the user a chance to edit To: CC: etc without making a new form just to handle that. I've got the following code-behind to handle an "Email Form" button for emailing the URL of the webform.

```
protected void fvBF_ItemCommand(object sender, FormViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Email")
    {
        Label lblBFID = (Label)fvBookingForm.FindControl("lblBFID");
        Label lblProjectID = (Label)fvBookingForm.FindControl("lblProjectNum");
        Label lblProjectName = (Label)fvBookingForm.FindControl("lblProjectName");
        Label lblReleaseName = (Label)fvBookingForm.FindControl("lblReleaseName");
        Label lblPMName = (Label)fvBookingForm.FindControl("lblPM");

        String strReleaseName = String.IsNullOrEmpty(lblReleaseName.Text) ? "[Description]" : lblReleaseName.Text;

        String pmFirst = lblPMName.Text.ToString().Split()[0];
        String pmLast = lblPMName.Text.ToString().Split()[1];

        String strSubject = "BF " + lblBFID.Text + " - " + lblProjectName.Text  + " - Release " + strReleaseName;
        String strBody = "A Booking Form for Project #"+ lblProjectID.Text + " - " + lblProjectName.Text + 
            " - Release " + strReleaseName + " has been created or modified. \n\n" + Request.Url.ToString();

        Process.Start("mailto:" + pmFirst + "." + pmLast + "@company.com?subject=" +
            HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(strSubject) + "&body=" +
            HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(strBody).Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine));
    }
}
```

However, when the email is generated, there are no line breaks in the body between the "A Booking Form...." sentence and the URL. I've tried putting Environment.NewLine directly in the string.

`...created or modified. " + Environment.Newline + Environment.NewLine + Request.Url.ToString();`

Which basically gives me the same results. I've tried replacing the \n with `<br />` which doesn't add the line break and for some reason, doesn't display the URL either. I can only guess that the problem has to do with the HtmlAttributeEncode() and getting it to parse the NewLine properly. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: have you tried \r\n ?

Comment: You know many users don't have an email client installed on their computers these days and just use web based mail? Perhaps this is a corporate environment where you know everyone has Outlook, but for a public application this isn't a good idea.

Comment: It is for a corporate intranet app and Outlook is a part of standard PC deployment. Those that will be using this on a BYOD device won't be using email through it.

Comment: You're opening a process on the asp.net server.. How is this going work?

Comment: Why not format it in HTML in the first place?

Comment: This code is running on the web server? Process.Start runs on the server machine, as @maxbeaudoin alludes to. This will not work at that point. You would need to have an application running on the client machine to call Process.Start. You *could* embed your `mailto:` URI in a webpage however.

Comment: Hrmmmm. I've been doing all this on the IIS Express in Visual Studio... I just tried publishing to the IIS test server and I'm getting an exception error.

I may just have to bite the bullet and make a form for To: and CC: and just code the sending using System.Net.Mail

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try `.Replace("\r\n", "<br />")` on the body *after* you have done your encoding of the body.

Comment: .Replace("\r\n", "<br />") will works for HTML format email body.

Comment: That gets me the following output, again still on one line.

`...created or modified. <br />http://localhost:49768/BookingForm/538`

Comment: The <br />  will force a new line when viewed in an html email.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) here instead of String.

You can then do the following:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.AppendLine(string.Format("A Booking Form for Project #{0} - {1}",lblProjectID.Text, lblProjectName.Text));
builder.AppendLine(string.Format(" - Release {0}  has been created or modified.", strReleaseName));
builder.AppendLine();
builder.AppendLine(Request.Url.ToString());
String strBody = builder.ToString();
```

You can also include (char)10 and (char)13 in your string creation. e.g.:

```
string.Format("First Line{0}{1}Second Line", (char)10, (char)13);
```

Answer (score 0):

Model.Message = "my message \n second message";

then add this style to string tag style="white-space: pre-line;"
example `<h3 style="white-space: pre-line;">@Model.Message</h3>`